# Managing large objects across a cluster.

Tags: architecture, hash, routes, distributed-computing, cluster-computing

What kind of architecture should I use for the app below?

In our SAAS app each customer gets a directory of files. These files can be quite large, and need to be read and written to very quickly. Sometimes a customer will see very heavy usage and will need to have the files replicated across multiple boxes to handle the load. Any changes to the files need to replicated within a reasonable period of time (less than a minute).

Each customer gets a subdomain, customername.mydomain.com. Somehow requests to this subdomain need to get routed to a box that contains the customer's files. Customers need to be added to the system and assigned to boxes dynamically.

I was thinking of just having a list of servers and then hashing on the customer name to assign the customer, but that makes it difficult to add additional boxes.

We're using Amazon to host the app. S3 can be part of the solution. But the files can't live on S3 alone because there's no fast random access to file content.

I need to know how to assign customers to boxes, how to manage replication, how to route subdomains properly, and how to do it in a dynamic manner. Our preferred language is Java, but other languages are ok.

I realize this is a giant question. I doubt there are out-of-the-box solutions, but please list them if there are.

Comment: What protocol are you using to access files? HTTP?

Comment: The files need to be local to the server accessing them. I need super-fast random access.

Comment: IMO this question is too broad for SO. I voted to close... solving this problem may require a lot of effort.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you are already in AWS, use cloud formation to spin up a box on demand, add an ELB in front, that handles your routing issue.

On box spin-up, download the files from S3 for that customer onto the local disk.

Set up a job that runs every 30-60 seconds to check for new files up on S3, and push/pulls them down on demand.